# How to root Casio Commando phone

Tags: rooting

I have the latest version of the Casio Commando.  I can't seem to get it to be rooted.  It is running the latest update and so its at Android 2.3.  Anyone know if it is possible, I remember reading somewhere that Casio locked down this phone and so access to the bootloader is next to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 10/20/12, no one has ever rooted the Commando. XDA Developers forum is home to some of the innovators in the Droid world, and no one there has yet come up with a way.

Couple of reference points for you:

- [Casio G'zOne Commando](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1311582)
- [[Q] Casio Commando 2.3.3 root-impossible](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1292287)